# Sistema de turnos segun la hora, javascript

Tags: javascript

Estoy haciendo un sistema que según la hora UTC, vaya cambiando cada una hora, pero no me esta saliendo la parte donde se me ejecuta el tema de turnos, el código es este:

```javascript
const Reloj = function () {
      let fecha = new Date();
      let hora = fecha.getUTCHours();
      let mins = fecha.getUTCMinutes();
      let secs = fecha.getUTCSeconds();
    
      if (hora < 10) { hora = '0' + hora; }
      if (mins < 10) { mins = '0' + mins; }
      if (secs < 10) { secs = '0' + secs; }
    
      document.getElementById("reloj").innerHTML = `${hora} : ${mins} :  ${secs}  `
}
    
const calculo = function () {
      let utc = new Date();
      let hora = utc.getUTCHours();
      let mins = utc.getUTCMinutes();
      let secs = utc.getUTCSeconds();
     
      let resetHora = 24;
      let resetMin = 60;
      let resetSec = 60;
    
      let horaRestante = resetHora - hora  ;
      let minutosRestante =  resetMin -  mins;
      let segundosRestante =   resetSec - secs;
 
      document.getElementById("relojReset").innerHTML = `${horaRestante} : ${minutosRestante} :  ${segundosRestante}  `
      return horaRestante
}
   
setInterval(Reloj, 1000)
setInterval(calculo, 1000)
   
function groups(){
      let hour;
      let minuts;
    
      let or = new Date();
      let ut = or.getUTCHours(); //hora
      let it = or.getUTCMinutes(); //minutos
  
      if (ut == 03 || ut == 04 && it >=40){
        document.getElementById("group").innerHTML = "Grupo 1"
      }
      if(ut == 04 || ut == 05 && it >= 40){
        document.getElementById("group").innerHTML = "Grupo 2 aaa"  
      }
    
      //Este  
      if(ut == 07 || ut == 08 >=40){
        document.getElementById("group").innerHTML = "Grupo 3 aaa" 
      }
    
      //si es mayor o igual a 6 y es menor o igual a 40
      if(ut == 09 || ut == 10 >=40){
        document.getElementById("group").innerHTML = "Grupo 1"
      }
    
      //si es mayor o igual a 7 y es menor o igual a 40  
      if(ut == 11 || ut == 12 >=40){
        document.getElementById("group").innerHTML = "Grupo 2 aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa"
      }
      if(ut >= 13 && it >=40){
        document.getElementById("group").innerHTML = "Grupo 3 aa"
      }
      if(ut >= 09 && it >=40){
        document.getElementById("group").innerHTML = "Grupo 1"
      }
      if(ut >= 10 && it >=40){
        document.getElementById("group").innerHTML = "Grupo 2"
      }
      if(ut >= 11 && it >=40){
        document.getElementById("group").innerHTML = "Grupo 3 aaa"
      }
      if(ut >= 12 && it >=40){
        document.getElementById("group").innerHTML = "Grupo 1"
      }
      if(ut >= 13 && it >=40){
        document.getElementById("group").innerHTML = "Grupo 2 afsafasd"
      }
      if(ut >= 14 && it >=40){
        document.getElementById("group").innerHTML = "Grupo 3"
      }
      if(ut >= 15 && it >=40){
        document.getElementById("group").innerHTML = "Grupo 1"
      }
      if(ut >= 16 && it >=40){
        document.getElementById("group").innerHTML = "Grupo 2"
      }
      if(ut >= 17 && it >=40){
        document.getElementById("group").innerHTML = "Grupo 3 aaa"
      }
      if(ut >= 18 && it >=40){
        document.getElementById("group").innerHTML = "Grupo 1"
      }
      if(ut >= 19 && it >=40){
        document.getElementById("group").innerHTML = "Grupo 2"
      }
      if(ut >= 20 && it >=40){
        document.getElementById("group").innerHTML = "Grupo 3"
      }
      if(ut >= 21 && it >=40){
        document.getElementById("group").innerHTML = "Grupo 1"
      }
      if(ut >= 22 && it >=40){
        document.getElementById("group").innerHTML = "Grupo 2"
      }
      if(ut >= 23 && it >=40){
        document.getElementById("group").innerHTML = "Grupo 3"
      }
      if(ut >= 00 && it >=40){
        document.getElementById("group").innerHTML = "Grupo 1"
      }
      if(ut == 02 || ut == 03 && it >=40){
        document.getElementById("group").innerHTML = "Grupo 2 fdafdasdfasfasd"
      }
      if(ut == 02 || ut == 03 && it >=40){
        document.getElementById("group").innerHTML = "Grupo 3 aaaa"
      }
      console.log(ut, it)
}
 
setInterval(groups, 1000)
```

El código creo por mi parte esta muy incompleto, algunas cosas se podrían hacer dentro de una misma función, pero me gustaría refactorizarlo cuando funcione.

en la función `groups()` lo que hago es volver a tomar los datos de la hora UTC, y dentro de los `if`, mi idea era comparar la hora y los minutos de modo que:

> 03:40 hasta 04:40 -> Grupo 3

> 04:40 hasta 05:40 -> Grupo 1

> 05:40 hasta 06:40 -> Grupo 2

Y así constantemente, pero la forma en la que hice la sentencia en los `if` no me estaría funcionando correctamente, e intente de muchas otras formas hasta que se me quemo el cerebro pero siempre me tira algo erróneo,

Muchas gracias por su ayuda.

Saludos!

Comment: Te aconsejo quitar las llaves de tus if de una sola línea, ya que ahí  no las necesitas y puedes ahorrar mucho espacio a la larga. No ayuda mucho en el problema base, pero no las necesitas.

Comment: Gracias, lo voy a hacer

Comment: Hola, qué es exactamente lo que no está funcionando? Agrega el error o la salida esperada así es mas fácil ayudarte. Te recomiendo que leas: https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: Hola, lo que no funciona es el tema de detectar que grupo entra en cada hora, creo que el sistema de los if esta mal hecho

Comment: Si, en efecto, están mal hechas las condiciones de los `if`. Por lo que te recomiendo que agregues en tu pregunta un ejemplo mínimo de lo que quieres lograr, esto sería: Para una entrada específica, qué salida deseas obtener. Así podemos ayudarte